# name 'sp' is not defined spottily

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, spotipy

I am working with numpy and spotipy to retrieve my playlist. This is the code I have problem with

```
def get_features_for_playlist(uri):
    playlist_id = uri.split(':')[2]
    results = sp.user_playlist(username, playlist_id)
```

It is constantly giving me error

```
NameError: name 'sp' is not defined
```

can someone please help me. I have tried searching on the spottily documentation but it is showing the same code I am using here.

Comment: Have you imported spotipy?

Comment: Take a look at how `sp` is defined in, for example, [this code](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#module-spotipy.client).

Comment: Yes. I have imported spotipy. But it is now showing : module 'spotipy' has no attribute 'user_playlist'

Comment: Hi,
I found the error!

I had to put `sp = spotipy.Spotify()`. It's now working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you write:

```
sp = spotipy.Spotify()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, try adding:

```
from spotipy import Spotify as sp
```

as the first line of the code, it didn't look like you'd imported `spotipy`.

Comment: module 'spotipy' has no attribute 'user_playlist'

Comment: @AryajPandey Try now